# The GridView 'PendingRecordsGridview' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled

Tags: asp.net, gridview, row, delete-row

I've searched in google there's an easy way to delete a record with confirmation using this code:

```
<asp:templatefield HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:templatefield>
```

But when i run it and click delete and clicking "yes" to confirm. this error appears: 
The GridView 'PendingRecordsGridview' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled.

Somebody Help me :( i've also tried adding this code ``OnRowDeleting = "PendingRecordsGridview_RowDeleting" but no success! :(

Here's my gridview full code:

```
<asp:GridView OnPageIndexChanging="PendingRecordsGridview_PageIndexChanging" ID="PendingRecordsGridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowcommand="PendingRecordsGridview_RowCommand" DataSourceID="sd1" BorderStyle="Ridge" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" Width="1070px" PageSize="2" AllowPaging="True">
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Accept">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button CommandArgument='<%# Bind("id") %>' ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="accept" Text="Accept" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Middle Name" SortExpression="MiddleLastName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MiddleName") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MiddleName") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Contact No." SortExpression="ContactNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContactNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContactNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Plate No." SortExpression="PlateNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PlateNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PlateNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Mobile Color" SortExpression="Color">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Color") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Color") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Brand" SortExpression="Brand">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Brand") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Brand") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Liscenced No." SortExpression="LiscensedNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LiscensedNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LiscensedNumber") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>Image</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("Image") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image")) : string.Empty %>' alt="image" height="85" width="85"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="#003399" />
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            NO PENDING REQUEST!
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#999999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="3px" BorderStyle="Ridge" />
    </asp:GridView>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 282px">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 37px">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" id="sd1" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PendingRecords]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [PendingRecords] WHERE [ID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [PendingRecords] ([Username], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleName], [Address], [Gender], [ContactNumber], [PlateNumber], [Color], [Brand], [LiscensedNumber]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [PendingRecords] SET [Username] = ?, [Password] = ?, [FirstName] = ?, [LastName] = ?, [MiddleName] = ?, [Address] = ?, [Gender] = ?, [ContactNumber] = ?, [PlateNumber] = ?, [Color] = ?, [Brand] = ?, [LiscensedNumber] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 33px">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 32px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 8px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 87px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 542px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 447px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 83px; width: 34px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please modify your markup and code to include the `OnRowDeleting` event.

```
<asp:GridView OnPageIndexChanging="PendingRecordsGridview_PageIndexChanging" ID="PendingRecordsGridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowcommand="PendingRecordsGridview_RowCommand" DataSourceID="sd1" BorderStyle="Ridge" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" Width="1070px" PageSize="2" AllowPaging="True">
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnRowDeleting="PendingRecordsGridview_RowDeleting"/>
```

On the code behind add this method.

```
public void PendingRecordsGridview_RowDeleting (Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: I added the code and it still giving me the same error :/

Comment: @scartag Can you explain why it is necessary to add the rowDeleting-event, even when left empty?

Comment: @Brabbeldas I think the grid throws an error if you don't implement it and a delete command is fired.

Answer (score 26):

You are trying with a command name of **Delete** for your delete button. So the gridview creates a **row deleting** event automatically....

You need to change the command argument from **Delete** to something else like **Delete_Product** or whatever...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I spent far too long trying to figure out what was going on in a situation where one of my commands was working fine, yet another was not working until I refreshed the page. I had one column with `CommandName="Archive"`, and it worked just fine. Another column with `CommandName="Delete"` would not work, even though they went through the same code on the backend. I implemented the accepted answer and it did work. But then I tried changing the second one to `CommandName="DeleteQuote"` (I'm working with `Quote` objects), and it worked, just like that.