# How can I delete entire row in my SQL datagridview?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net, vba

**How can I delete an entire row in my datagridview.. I already have a delete link in my datagrid..
Here is my markup code in vb**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="EmployeeHallway" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" Height="93px" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="6" style="margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center;" Width="768px">
              <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
              <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>

                               <%--ADD THE DELETE LINK BUTTON--%>
                               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Runat="server" OnClientClick ="return confirm('Are you sure you?');"
                                   CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Locker ID" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeNo" HeaderText="EmployeeNo" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" />
              </Columns>
              <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003366" BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" ForeColor="White" />
              <PagerStyle BackColor="#003366" BorderColor="#336699" ForeColor="White" />
              <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003366" />
              <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#6600FF" />
              <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

And when I click the delete link this error shows

> "The GridView 'EmployeeHallway' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled. "

Can anyone help me what to do next

Comment: possible duplicate of [The GridView 'PendingRecordsGridview' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301815/the-gridview-pendingrecordsgridview-fired-event-rowdeleting-which-wasnt-handl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Delete` as the `CommandName` for the delete link so it will automatically creates a `RowDeleting` event. So you have to implement it like this:

You have to add `OnRowDeleting` event as below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="EmployeeHallway" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" Height="93px" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="6" style="margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center;" Width="768px">
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnRowDeleting="EmployeeHallway_RowDeleting"/>
```

And at the code-behind:

```
Public Sub EmployeeHallway_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: correct me if im wrong but this code is for c# right? i need code for VB environment sir.

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting"` in aspx page

Saving Your DataTable in `ViewState("dt")` and then Do Like this:

```
Protected Sub OnRowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex)
    Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(ViewState("dt"), DataTable)
    dt.Rows(index).Delete()
    ViewState("dt") = dt
    BindGrid()
End Sub

 Protected Sub BindGrid()
    EmployeeHallway.DataSource = TryCast(ViewState("dt"), DataTable)
    EmployeeHallway.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: BindGrid() got an error " BindGrid is not declared."

Comment: this error occured "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "

Comment: are You saving Your `DataTable` in `ViewState("dt")`??

Comment: how can i save my data table? is the data table and data gridview the same? hehe  im still a newbie on this sorry

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView---Delete-Row-with-Confirmation.aspx refer this

Comment: there's an error occuring on this line :dt.Rows(index).Delete() "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "