# Why does my rowcommand event handler not work here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, event-handling, buttonfield

I am trying to handle the event in which a button in my button field is pressed and subsequently removes the row from the website and from the database.  and I do that but using the following code in my .aspx.cs file:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("testing buttons");
        }
    }
```

However, whenever I go to click a button in the button field, it throws the error saying that the event is not handled.  The following code is the aspx for the entire data table.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewStudent" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
      emptydatatext="There are no data to display">
      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
      <Columns>
          <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="True" Text="Remove" />
      </Columns>
      <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
      <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
      <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
      <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
      <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
      <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />



</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: In codehind it's `GridView1_RowCommand` then at the aspx the GridView called `ID="gridViewStudent"`? Plus there is no onrowcommand=`GridView1_RowCommand` on it.

Comment: Change your event name to `gridViewStudent_RowCommand` and add proper event handler on the control: `OnRowCommand="gridViewStudent_RowCommand"`.

Comment: It says that OnRowCommand is not a valid attribute of element ButtonField

Comment: For what reason that you're adding `OnRowCommand` to `ButtonField`? Try to place the handler at parent `GridView` instead.

Comment: Share us the exception message threw when you click.

Comment: After all of the changes it still goes into an error and says that the event is not being handled.

Comment: System.Web.HttpException: The GridView 'gridViewStudent' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled.

Comment: @Sohee Try adding `OnRowDeleting="gridViewStudent_RowDeleting"` event handler to your `GridView` and ensure this added to code behind: `protected void gridViewStudent_RowDeleting(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The GridView 'PendingRecordsGridview' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301815/the-gridview-pendingrecordsgridview-fired-event-rowdeleting-which-wasnt-handl)

Comment: thank you for the help, it will now go into the event successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you're not declaring all required event handlers to the `GridView`. Use proper event handlers and event handler methods for respective actions:

**Page Markup (ASPX)**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewStudent" runat="server" ...
      OnRowCommand="gridViewStudent_RowCommand"
      OnRowDeleting="gridViewStudent_RowDeleting">

</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind (ASPX.CS)**

```
// Row command event
protected void gridViewStudent_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}

// Row deleting event
protected void gridViewStudent_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```